# swift localization translation from english to other language

Tags: swift, localization

If I have a hard coded list in an array(This is my sample code):

```
let general = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        general = ["food", "water", "exercise"]
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return general.count
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MenuTableCell", for: indexPath) as! MenuTableCell
        cell.menuListItem.text! = general[indexPath.row]
        tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.none

        return cell
    }
```

and I printed out on the side bar. How do I localize the general array?

Comment: Do you know how to localize a single string using `NSLocalizedString`?

Comment: I mostly found tutorial about translating globally...like adding a files under the localizations under project there

Comment: This is not a tiny topic that is easily answered in a short Q&A. As rmaddy notes, the tool you want is `NSLocalizedString`, but there are more steps than that. Start here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: If you use pods then you can try `L10n-swift`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a tutorial which will be helpful to you. Refer this [link](https://medium.com/lean-localization/ios-localization-tutorial-938231f9f881).

To translate your general array you can create a global file from where you can create variables that can be accessed globally.

Constant.swift file //For all variables

```
let food = NSLocalizedString("food", comment: "")
let water = NSLocalizedString("water", comment: "")
let exercise = NSLocalizedString("exercise", comment: "")
```

Localizable.strings (Base)

```
"food" = "Food";
"water" = "Water";
"exercise" = "Exercise";
```

Localizable.strings (Other)

```
"food" = "Food";
"water" = "Water";
"exercise" = "Exercise";
```

Viewcontroller.swift

```
let general = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        general = [food, water, exercise]
}
```

Hope you understand how to implement localization in your application.

Comment: I tried dy but i only get to print out food instead of any chinese word... And i cant access to the tutorial you embed there

Comment: @ShawnChen You need to change "Food", "Water", "Exercise" with its Chinese word. Have you changed that in Localizable.strings (Other)?

Comment: yes I did. But it only showing me the 

let food = NSLocalizedString("food", comment: "")

its showing me the food instead of chinese word food...i not sure why but others words like button or titles I manage to translate them to chinese. Except for the side menu...

Comment: Friend it works for me. Now I need code to check what's wrong. Have you refer link mentioned in the answer?

Comment: I cant access to the link you gave...TT

Comment: regarding on the localized file do i need to make another for my global.swift file? or its fine for me to place it under the main storyboard?

Comment: https://medium.com/lean-localization/ios-localization-tutorial-938231f9f881 now try again.

Comment: TT...i cant access

Comment: Okay, do one more thing don't create the constant file. `let food = NSLocalizedString("food", comment: "")` use this in viewDidLoad function.

Comment: have you add the localizations in your project info (tab beside Build Setting) ?